# What happens if you modify the variables in an activity while it is paused?

Tags: android

I understand that when an activity is paused, as stated by the documentation, all variables will retain their values.

However, if I have a service running at the same time, and try to assign to, or modify the value of a public variable in a paused activity, what happens?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, if I have a service running at the same time, and try to assign to, or modify the value of a public variable in a paused activity, what happens?

You're changing the value on your `Activity`'s member variable.

Comment: So the value will change despite the activity being puased? And will remain changed when the activity resumes?